# Airmatic Suspension for an S-Class Mercedes Benz

Tags: suspension

I parked my 2003 S430 for about 2 hours with the front wheels turned to the right (not straightened). When I came back and drove the car, immediately the warning appears "Airmatic Too Low!!" I was puzzled for a few seconds but then the warning suddenly disappeared and the car run normally. Can someone tell me why or what happened to my car? Do I need to have the Airmatic Suspension checked by a Mercedes mechanic? Was it wrong to park my S430 with the tyres turned? A month ago on periodic service, all the air suspension shock absorbers were reported good/no leaking indicated. Please someone advise, thank you.